# Verbs and Verbals -- Why can't I write "(the) expense to make (someone do something)"?

Tags: verb-forms, verbal-noun

> The hope is that the sheer expense to make producers pay for the disposal of their computer equipment wherever it is sold or being used across the world, will spur the industry towards making "greener" machines.

Well, my textbook says that the phrase "to make" should be replaced by "of making" and "being" should be added before the word "sold". Can anyone provide an explanation?

Comment: There are not many nouns that can license (or allow) a *to*-infinitive as its (post-)modifier. Among these are *order, way, ability, time, attempt, right, power, desire, reason*. For most other nouns, you'll need to use *of VERB-ing* instead (e.g. *expense of making ...*).

Answer (score 1):

You're right about the first point. Ordinarily *expense* take *of* phrases as complement, not infinitives.

You're wrong about the second point. There's no reason to cast this in the progressive, and a good reason not to: putting it in the progressive would imply that producers would be responsible for disposal only in places where their equipment is currently sold or used.

And you missed the real howler. The *cost of making producers pay* is not a cost to the producers, but a cost to the authority imposing the obligation, the cost of enforcing whatever laws are put in place, and consequently doesn't act as an incentive to producers—quite the contrary. What the author presumably means is something like:

> The hope is that the sheer cost to producers of having to pay for the disposal . . .

There's also an awkwardness in using *expense* here, in the sense "expensiveness"; in contexts suggesting balance-sheet calculations *expense* means something a bit different from *cost*.

It's very careless writing.