# When do I use preposition in + ing?

Tags: prepositions, to-infinitive, gerund-clauses

I am confused while using the preposition "in" in the below context.

> *The wider provision of electricity supplies is a critical factor **in reducing** global poverty levels?*

Why can't I say *"...a critical factor **to reduce** global poverty levels?"*

I am not sure the exact meaning of "in" in the context.

When do I use proposition "in" with "ing" form?

Comment: Good question (+1). I think when the action is expected to be lasting long *or perhaps permanent* and **not** for time being, 'in+ing' suits better. Said that, the wider provision of electricity supplies is a critical factor in reducing global poverty levels - it is a long term solution, a continuous solution to the problem

Comment: @MaulikV Waiting for your answer, Sir.

Comment: Not sure about the answer. Therefore, you see that as a comment! :) @RuchirM

Comment: Here is a similar question: [Verbs and Verbals -- Why can't I write "(the) expense to make (someone do something)"?](http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/62696/3281). In the old question, it was about *expense of*, in this question, it's about *factor in*.

Answer (score 1):

The noun **factor** means "one that does" (from Latin 'facere').  We usually employ it to designate *one of several* driving forces or important parts helping or hindering a process.

The process here is the *reduction of global poverty levels*.  I am certain that you can identify some other factors that play their roles (positive or negative) along with the "wider provision of electricity supplies".  Considering that they all take part, often simultaneously, to influence the process' outcome, you can think of them as *actors **in** a play* or *gears **in** a gearbox*.  That's why they are *factors **in** something*.

Another way of looking at *factors* comes from mathematics.  A *factor* is a prime number, often one of several that make up a given number by multiplication.  For instance, number 24 is made up from 2*2*2*3.  Each of those (three 2s and a 3) is a *factor* **in** 24* (because they comprise it).

You can use preposition '***in***' with other gerunds like you would with nouns.

> My experiences ***in*** answering SE questions helped my own growth.
>   His efforts to answer a question ended ***in*** doing somebody's homework.